# Is Vue native is still used?

Tags: android, ios, vue.js, vue-native

I am a Vue front end developer,
I saw few moments ago that I can build phone app via Vue-native ..

But once I entered its documentation I could read :

> Vue Native has been deprecated and is no longer maintained.

So it will be useful to learn and work through it (Vue native) ?

Or no longer technical support or toturial that it will be difficult to work with ?

Comment: If it's deprecated there is no point of learning it. If you want to do native development there more and popular option out there you can go for it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not related to flutter

Comment: It's unwise to start with deprecated library, especially if it's something like native bridge that requires constant maintenance you can't handle on your own. So the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to develop mobile app using Vue.Js(without learning new mobile app development language), then Quasar Framework is the one for you.

You can develop Cordova App or Capacitor App with both Vite and Webpack.

[Cordova Apps Using Vite](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-cordova-apps/introduction)

[Capacitor Apps Using Vite](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-capacitor-apps/introduction)

[Cordova Apps Using Webpack](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-cordova-apps/introduction)

[Capacitor Apps Using Webpack](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-capacitor-apps/introduction)